# javascript runtime error trying to display notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I found the following code that displays toast-style alerts in mobile web applications and I want to use it to show these messages to users in the mobile client:

```
var toast = function (msg) {
$("<div class='ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-e ui-corner-all'><h3>" + msg + "</h3></div>")
.css({
    display : "block",
    opacity : 0.90,
    position : "fixed",
    padding : "7px",
    text-align : "center",
    width : "270px",
    left : ($(window).width() - 284) / 2,
    top : $(window).height() / 2
})
.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer).delay(1500)
.fadeOut(400, function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
}
```

I call it from javascript like this:

```
toast("This is a test message");
```

When I navigate to the page where this code is located, it shows the message fine the first time.  When I go back to the page (after visiting it the first time), I get this error:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'pageContainer' of undefined or null reference

What is causing this to error and how can I resolve the error? I want the function to be able to execute no matter how many times the page is visited.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Yes I am.  What I want to do is to use this function as a general javascript alert replacement.